# Existence of root of derivative $P'(x)$ between any $2$ roots of polynomial $P(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

*Question*: If **P(x)** is a Polynomial then *show that between any $2$ roots of the polynomial, there exists a root of **P'(x)*** where **P'(x)** denotes the derivative of the Polynomial.

Please help guys. Unable to find any information which relates polynomials and derivatives in Real Analysis.

Comment: Mean Value Theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Let's $a$ and $b$ two zeros of $P(x)$ (that is $P(a) = P(b) = 0$). Since the polynomial is continuous and differentiable over $[a,b]$, then [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem) guarantees that there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$$P'(c) = 0.$$

Comment: Ahh, 1 minute late! I knew I should have typed faster...;)

Comment: @Aniket: Be happy. Worse is me that I have to fight with the English first and also with Tex Commands...Too many times when I finish my task, they have already been published several answers what makes me give up publishing.

Answer (score 2):

Say the 2 roots of the polynomial are $a$ and $b$. 
Therefore, $$P(a) = P(b) = 0$$
Now,
$P(x)$ being a polynomial must be continuous and differentiable in [a,b]. 
then from Rolle's Theorem, we can conclude that there exists at least one $c \in$ $]a,b[$ such that
$$P'(c) = 0$$